# Problem in python when creating a QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a problem with the command **make** in the python.

I used the:

`Run->cmd` and go to the location of your plugin builder

(i.e: *c:/users/rafik_pc/.qgis2/python/plugins/pluginbuilder*) type the following command:

```
pyrcc4 -py2 resources.qrc -o resources.py
```

(I used `-py2` because I'm using **python 2.7**)

restart QGIS and DONE.

But the problem persists.

How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @AntonioPadez! You may need to do this from the **OSGeo4W Shell** program, not cmd. This should come with your QGIS installation (e.g. `Start > All Programs > QGIS 2.18 > OSGeo4W Shell`).

Answer (score 3):

In your **OSGeo4W Shell** program, go to the current directory of your plugin using:

```
cd c:/users/rafik_pc/.qgis2/python/plugins/SaveAttributes
```

Then type:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

No need to use `make`.